# the gift that I gave her vs. the gift that I gave to her?

Tags: usage

> the gift that I gave her vs. the gift that I gave to her

Is the latter acceptable?
Both ***I gave her the gift.***  and ***I gave the gift to her.*** are correct. So, I think ***the gift that I gave to her*** should be correct. Which do you use more frequently?

Answer (score 1):

> - 1 the gift that I gave her
> - 2 the gift that I gave to her

Both 1 and 2 are grammatical, and their meaning is essentially the same. 1 would now be a more common form, 2 sounds a bit old-fashioned, at least in US usage.